# IPhone - NSKeyedUnarchiver memory leak

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nskeyedarchiver

I am using `NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:` to read in application data.  When running with Leaks in Instruments, I am told that the following produces a leak:

```
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *archivePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@/Config.archive", documentsDirectory];

    //Following line produces memory leak
    applicationConfig = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:archivePath];

    [archivePath release];

    if( applicationConfig == nil )
    {
        applicationConfig = [[Config alloc]init];
    }
    else
    {
        [applicationConfig retain];
    }
}
```

The line:

`applicationConfig = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:archivePath];`

is producing a memory leak of 32 Bytes.  applicationConfig is an instance variable.  My initWithCode function simply does:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if( self = [super init] )
    {
                //NSMutableArray
        accounts = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"Accounts"] retain];
        //Int
                activeAccount = [coder decodeIntForKey:@"ActiveAccount"];       
    }
    return self;
}
```

Any idea of why

`applicationConfig = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:archivePath];`

is producing a leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your memory leak is caused by this line:

```
[applicationConfig retain];
```

or this line:

```
accounts = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"Accounts"] retain];
```

The memory is being *allocated* in `unarchiveObjectWithFile:`, but the leak will be caused by an extra retain on the object. Make sure that you are releasing `applicationConfig` appropriately.

Comment: I thought I read that I have to retain the object that is returned since I didn't alloc it myself.  Can you shed any light on this?

Comment: Yes, you do have to retain it. Because you retained it, you also have to release it somewhere. The memory leak will be cause by the lack of the release.

Comment: I release the applicationConfig in the dealloc method of the application delegate ( where all this code resides ).  So then I still don't understand the reported leak.  Is it possible it thinks there will be a leak since it doesn't see a matching release in the same method?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You also have to release it before `applicationConfig` is set to any other value. The same applies for the `accounts` member variable.

Comment: Ah HA!  I found it.  I am an idiot.  I wasn't going far enough down in the stack trace in instruments.  I assumed since it didn't give me some where to click to drill down from the NSKeyedUnarchiver, that I couldn't go any further.  Account is an object and has its own initWithCoder.  Eventually there is a call to SFHFKeychainUtils ( makes saving to key chain easier ) that gives me the password for the account.  The call to SFHFKeychainUtils is producing the memory leak.  Thanks for your help.